# No se ejecuta nada después del sscanf()

Tags: c++

Soy nuevo en c++, estuve revisando el codigo que puso mi profesor como ejemplo en clase y en el main, el código deja de ejecutarse después del `sscanf()`, cuando lo quito las demás instrucciones se ejecutan normalmente, alguien sabe a que se debe?

```
int main(int nArg, char *Arg[]){
    int start;
    int stop;
    int step;
    int length;
    int i;
    
    int xValue[100];
    int yValue[100];
    
    int coeff[3] = {3, -4, 1};
    
    sscanf(Arg[1], "%d", &start);
    sscanf(Arg[2], "%d", &stop);
    sscanf(Arg[3], "%d", &step);
    
    //ESTO YA NO SE EJECUTA
    
    length = FillArray(xValue, start, stop, step);
    
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
        printf("%d,%d\n", xValue[i], PolyVal(xValue[i], coeff, 3));

}
```

Comment: Creo que lee una direccion de memoria que no existe, intenta llamar al programa compilado con mas de 2 argumentos desde la consola: `app.exe 1 2 4` a ver que resultado dá.

Comment: En tiempo de ejecucción la consola se detiene y deja de funcionar?, si es así lee el comentario de arriba.

Comment: Ohh vale, ya entiendo, muchas gracias, si es eso, pasando los argumentos directamente a la consola funciona correctamente, muchas gracias!

Comment: `int main(int,char**);` toma dos argumentos: El primero es un entero que indica la cantidad de cadenas almacendo en el segundo argumento, el segundo argumento es una matriz de cadenas que suele tener en el indice `0` la URL en la que se ejecuta el programa y los demas indice suele tener todo los argumento que pases por la consola a la apricacion. @Cgrk ¿te funcionó?, porque si es así voy a mudar los comentario a una respuesta.